# Windows - SQLite Active Critical Section

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite

I am using SQLite3 3.8.8.2 in a testlib.dll having an exported funtion void  DoDBOperation() that just opens database and then closes it. I've written an EXE that loads the DLL using LoadLibararyEx(), calls the function DoDBOperation() and finally unloads the DLL using FreeLibrary(). I do it 10000 times in a loop which leads to memory leak.

After investigation, I found that each time I load and unload testlib.dll, it leaks a critical section DS of 48 byte as reported by WinDBG after investigating heap. AppVerifier too reports that a library is being unloaded having an active critical section.

If I statically link the DLL such leak doesn't occur. I googled a lot but no help. I tried to debug sqlite3.c but didn't succeed in finding the leak.

Can someone provide some pointer on this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should call [sqlite3_shutdown](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/initialize.html) on dll unload to properly cleanup resources it allocated (e.g. in [DLL_PROCESS_DETACH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) handler).

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help. Critical section is still seen in windbg even if I call sqlite3_shutdown in DLL_PROCESS_DETACH handler. I think CS is created in process address space even though it's in DLL. So once a DLL is being detached from process, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH handler is called but sqlite3_shutdown() still leave CS (1 or more, I don't know) in active state.